# Clicking an image with no id in WebDriver using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, selenium, webdriver

I have a form with an image used as the submit button. The image has no id nor class attribute, and the form is submitted strictly with javascript. I am trying to use WebDriver (with PHP) to submit this little form. I am using the Firefox driver and selenium standalone server v 2.30.

The javascript function that exsist on the page being tested is `sendForm()`

I have tried to execute javascript via webdriver with no luck:

```
<?php
$js = "sendForm()";

$driver->execute(array(
    'script' => $js,
    'args' => array(),
));
?>
```

The image button looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="#">
    <!-- input fields go here -->
    <img src="/images/submit_button.png" alt="Go" onclick="sendForm();return false;">
</form>
```

So the two ways to submit this form would include 1) getting webdriver to execute sendForm() on its own, or 2) clicking the image which has no attributes to select.

Can I execute the javascript function some other way than what I have tried?

The form DOES have an id, so can I select the image via the form id and just 'click' it ?

Comment: You could try the form itself, but what about using the `src` from the image? Or even an XPath such as: `//form@id='myForm']/img` (if there is only one `img`)...

Comment: There are multiple identical "go" buttons on this page, unfortunately, so can't use src. I'm looking into the XPath selector now...

Comment: Using XPath worked, Arran!  $driver->get_element("xpath=//form[@id='myForm']//img")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use XPath. The below should work:

```
//form[@id='myForm']//img
```

This assumes there is only ever one `img` as a direct child of that particular form though, so  bear that in mind.